# How to fix endpoint error for npm audit fix?

Tags: npm, npm-audit

When I run 'npm audit fix' it returns

npm WARN audit Unable to authenticate && npm ERR! audit endpoint returned an error

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

You may change the registry by running below

```
npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

or add below to ~/.npmrc

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```